# Como identificar padrões em cores?

Tags: c#, imagem, cores, rgb

Eu tenho uma imagem e faço um loop percorrendo cada pixel da mesma.

Preciso identificar se a cor do pixel:
- É uma cor clara ou escura;
- E a tonalidade dele (por exemplo se ele é azulado ou avermelhado, esverdeado, etc...).

Estou usando como base os valores do RGB mas não venho tendo bons resultados.
Por exemplo:

Um tom de vermelho qualquer, aí quanto maior o numero do R no sistema RGB mais claro a cor é. Mas isso varia muito de cor para cor.

```
if (Color.DarkRed.R > 160) { // É um tom claro.}
```

Agradeço desde já!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você tem de fazer uma soma das três cores. No mínimo, R + G + B para obter o  brilho total e determinar se a cor é clara.

Como as cores vermelha e azul são mais escuras, uma transformação para preto-e-branco que dá uma noção melhor do brilho, é 0.21 R + 0.72 G + 0.07 B.

Quanto à tonalidade, eu pessoalmente converteria o valor RGB para HSV (tem algoritmos prontos por aí) mas outra forma rápida é

1) Achar o menor valor entre R, G e B;
2) Diminuir este valor das três cores;
3) De acordo com os valores que sobraram maiores que zero, determinar a tonalidade.

Aí você teria de implementar um grau de tolerância para cores muito fracas, por exemplo tom de pele é que cor? Vermelho? Laranja? Marrom? Outro desafio é lidar com cores compostas, tipo uma mistura com mais vermelho que verde é um tom de laranja, etc.